# card game engine with sql

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i am planning to create a card game engine using sql, the game consits of 4 human players and cards are in an sql table, now every thing is done regarding game logic and points, each game is manged by a seperate sql table, and players are able to create rooms

each room shall have a game table contains cards data with each player represnted in a column and a seperate chat table

1. if there was 1000 games running in the same
   time and each time a card played then a requst is made to the server
   either to remove a card from a players deck record player score and
   total game score, can this be handled in a single sql database
   without delayes and performance issues?
2. can i use global temporary tables ##sometable for each game room or
       do i have to create the tables manually and delete them after the
       game ends?
3. i would like also to know if storing chat data in a single sql
       table would make issues, one thing i thought of is saving chat data
       for all open rooms in a single datatable with a game id column, but
       would this give some performance issues if there was thausands of
       lines of chat data?
4. also what about a database for each game, would that be an over
   kill?
5. How such applications are managed normally?
6. do i have to use multiple servers and distribute the running games
       on them?
7. any ideas you have about optimizing such things

Comment: Your question is tagged with both `mysql` and `sql-server-2008-r2`?

Comment: It actually makes a big difference. MySQL contains more field types, and the storage capacity of each of their similar types can differ. Also, some commands are slightly different in implementation, and require you to alter your queries a little depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: It would make a difference to Service Broker, for example. Also, I cannot speak for how #tables or ##tables behave in mysql (I don't know if they even have global temps). In terms of performance, I believe they would perform differently for similar solutions.

Comment: PS. I've done this on a much smaller scale for poker. It was a LOT of fun :)

Comment: Learn about so called *Transactions*. If you are concerned about performance I'd say the vendor of your database-server-software should be able to solve that for you, keep it worry free on your end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider a memory-based cache system such as Velocity or Memcached to address the performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. The discussion of how to scale a task like this is a long one.
2. You could. But you should rather consider a smarter model whereby multiple games occur in a single table.
3. I would use [SQL Server Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for the chat
4. Yes.

I recommend you break your questions up into multiple questions so that contributers who specialise in a single aspect of your problem domain can contribute accordingly.

I don't know how `PHP` works; but I am fairly sure that it would be far more efficient for a lot of the game logic to occur client-side. Making a server call for every game action would work, my opinion is just that it is sub-optimal.

Comment: the reason i want to do all the game logic on the server is that there is a scoring system, when a player does a smart move then he gets more points and so on, i am still researching though but i need to know my limits!

Comment: You're going to have a lot of fun :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, I would expect live players to have at least 1 second delay before making their moves and only one play is making a move at a time per game. So roughly 1000 transactions per second peak for 1000 games.  Not an excessive load on modern architectures.
2. There is more overhead in most DBMSs for creating and destroying tables.  Keep it all in the same table.
3. Chat would be fine in a single table.  You could keep performance up by archiving chat from previous inactive games and removing from the primary live db.
4. Yes, very inefficient. Added complexity for no gain.
5. Not sure what you are asking.
6. Only as you scale. I would imagine you would start with a single db server until you needed more capacity.
7. Good design db design from the beginning from someone with experience will go a long ways. Don't waste too much time micro-optimizing at the get go or you will never get off the ground. Optimize as you need to as you scale.

Answer (score 0):

The short version is that relational DB such as SQL Server  are not very useful for games because they cannot efficiently store heavily structured hierarchical data

I would still advocate avoiding SQL, but there are now many more options in the `NoSQL` and for real performance you should consider using a Fast Temporary Storage such as [Redis](http://redis.io/) or Memcache

You can quickly look at [Cassandra vs MongoDB vs CouchDB vs Redis vs Riak vs HBase vs Couchbase vs Neo4j vs Hypertable vs ElasticSearch vs Accumulo vs VoltDB vs Scalaris comparison](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis)

Optimizing is a different topic entirely .. to wide and project specific .